# Render partial on button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble rendering a particle on a button click. I'm getting the error

> HelpController#FAQ_help is missing a template for this request format
>   and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []

**main_page.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "FAQ", FAQ_help_path  %>

<div id="content">

</div>
```

**help_controller.rb**

```
def FAQ_help
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.js
  end
end
```

**FAQ_help.js.erb**

```
$('#content').html("<%= render :partial => 'FAQ_help' %>");
```

**_FAQ_help.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <h1> This is the FAQ </h1>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'FAQ_help', to: 'help#FAQ_help'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
# main_page.html.erb
<%= link_to "FAQ", FAQ_help_path, remote: true %>
```

And

```
# faq_help.js.erb
$('#content').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'FAQ_help')%>")
#fixed syntax
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have created a method for this request I would define it a little more for clarity:

```
def FAQ_help
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.js {render: FAQ_help}
  end
end
```

If you want to keep your controllers clean I would pass a param with the link and check if the pram is present if it is render FAQ partial:

View:

```
<link_to "Your FAQ"  your_path, data: {method: :get, :remote => true, params: { faq: "#{current.user_name}" }.to_param }, :class =>"button" %>
```

Controller:

```
if params[:faq].present?
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.js {render: FAQ_help}
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.js {} #your default view for this method 
  end
end
```

This is handy to display IE:different content as per the request

```
ie: parms =bob # displays bobs FAQ
ie: parms =ted # displays teds FAQ
```

This technique is similar to what you would implement to create a search.